# Returning Empty Json Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to return a Json object in C#. I am new to MVC controller and using Json first time, I return this object, and its empty.

```
public class A
{
    private string name;
    public void set(string data)
    {
        name = data;
    }
    public string get()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
public JsonResult Hello()
{
    A obj = new A();
    obj.set("Abc");
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonVar = js.Serialize(obj);
    return Json(jsonVar, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that the framework can deduce that `get` and `set` set the private variable `name`'s value.. it doesn't.

Instead, make `name` a public property, and it should work:

```
public class A {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

A obj = new A() { Name = "Abc" };
/* ...etc... */
```

Think about this from the framework's point of view. How can it determine what `get` or `set` are doing? Are they accessing the same variable? Who knows.. its runtime after all. This is why methods can't be serialized the way you're assuming.

Comment: Thank you. If I don't want to make my class member public, Is there other way around ??

Comment: You can make the setter private or protected, but I think serialization requires a public getter (and deserialization would require a public setter).

Answer (score 4):

In C# we have properties which (in C# 3+) can be automatically created.

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly you will need to return your object wrapped in a new object in order for the JSON to return correctly. You do not need to serialize the object yourself (since you could just return it as an `ActionResult` otherwise).

```
public JsonResult Hello()
{
    A obj = new A();
    obj.Name = "Abc";
    return Json(new { obj }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This will create a new Json object `{"obj":{"Name":"Abc"}}`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn'd be naming methods `Get` and `Set` - not even `GetName` and `SetName`, because if I remember my C# readings right, the CLR does that by convention when "translating" properties into CIL code (the getter becomes a "get" method and the setter becomes a "set" method). The "right" way is to use properties with meaningful names - you'll thank yourself later:

```
private string _name;
public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name=value; } }
```