# C# - JsonConvert.SerializeObject returning empty JSON string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have looked at a couple of others SO questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891013/returning-empty-json-object) but my problem isn't compatible.

I have an `List<LatLng>` called `fireHazardsList` that I would like to convert into a JSON string. A `LatLng` object has a `float latitude, longitude`. I am trying to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to convert my `List` into a `JSON string` but currently my `JSON` is empty when this code is run.

`LatLng` is a [class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) found in Xamarin `Android.Gms.Maps.Model;`

```
fireHazardsList = new List<LatLng>();
populateHazardList();
string coordinates = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fireHazardsList, Formatting.Indented);
```

I am surely missing a step, but I am new to JSON and unsure what I am missing. Currently the JSON string I am being returned is like this:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

Here is a screenshot showing that my list is being populated just before the `SerializeObject()` function is called.

[image]

Comment: can you add class properties of  `LatLng` class

Comment: What does fireHazardsList.Any() return after populateHazardList? If true you're going to need to supply the code for LatLng.

Comment: can you please add json string and property of `LatLng` class ?

Comment: Sorry everyone I have edited my question explaining where LatLng is from

Comment: have you declared the class as Serializeable ?

Comment: Do you mean the LatLng class @Technacron?

Comment: yes exactly! did you ?

Comment: No I did not do that, how do I do that? The class is an inbuilt android.gms class

Comment: Ok! i will share and answer if found solution. On abstract I think you should override this class and make a subclass serialize-able

Comment: Your problem isn't the serialization - that's working fine. Your problem is you aren't getting any data. What are you doing in populateHazardList()?

Comment: I will edit my answer to show that my hazard list is populated

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Json.NET returns empty objects serializing list of Android.Gms.Maps.Model.LatLng objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45239996/3744182).

Comment: Thanks @dbc, can't believe I missed that

Comment: @BarneyChambers - well I just edited the title to more precisely reflect the contents of the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the `LatLng` class does not have `get;set;` properties, which is why the JSON rendering is empty.

Try this to create the properties on the fly:

```
string coordinates = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    fireHazardsList.Select(ll => new { ll.latitude, ll.longitude }),
    Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is somewhere in populateHazardList(); That isn't populating the data as you expect. The fact that you are seeing this:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

...shows that the serialization is happening correctly, but there's no data. You need to figure out why.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have updated my answer to show that my list is definitely being populated

Answer (score 0):

To create correct JSON first you need to prepare appropriate model:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class LatLang
    {
     [DataMember(Name = "lat")]
      public string Latitude { get; set; }

      [DataMember(Name = "longi")]
      public string Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

To be able to use Data attributes you will need to choose some other JSON serializer. For example DataContractJsonSerializer or Json.NET.

```
 LatLang latlangObj = new LatLang
 {
   Latitude = "something",
   Longitude = "something"
 };


string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
new
{
    jsonString = latlangObj
});
```

So jsonString variable will be:

```
  {
 "jsonString ": {
"lat": "something",
"longi": "someting"
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following peace of code correctly working for me:-

```
 List<LatLng> l = new List<LatLng>() ;
        l.Add(new LatLng { latitude=0.090f, longitude=90.8f});
        string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l);
```

Below is my LatLng class

```
public class LatLng
{
    public float latitude { get; set; }
    public float longitude { get; set; }
}
```